# Submit Confirmation Javascript Function Not Responding

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Good day guys,

Please assist. I have a function below been called on a submit button. It does not trigger. Am i missing out anything?

```
@section Scripts {

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/cssjqryUi")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type=datetime]').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-60:+0"
        });

    });


    function confirmSubmit() {

        if (confirm("Are you Sure to Submit!")) {

            alert("Customer Account Created Successfully");
        } else {


        }
</script>
```

}

The first function is for Jquery Datetime Picker and it works well but for the Submit do not. Below is the code for the submit tag

```
 <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="confirmSubmit()" />
```

Comment: You are missing a closing `}` on your `confirmSubmit` function

Comment: @blex, Thank you for the insight. It works now. However, even if i click on the Cancelbutton, it still get triggered. Am I missing anything? New to JS please

Comment: Change your HTML to `onclick="return confirmSubmit()"`, and in your script, do `else { return false; }` That will prevent the form from being submitted if you cancel

Comment: @blex, Than you so much. it works now. But lastly please, It does not display the successful alert after clicking OK. alert("Customer Account Created Successfully"); Am i putting in the wrong place?

Comment: It looks like it's in the correct place, it should be displayed https://jsfiddle.net/f04kca83/

Comment: Yeah it works that way but i have some fields check to see if they meet up requirement before posting. SO it still brings Account created successfully even when the form has returned the view back as some data inputted needs been checked. Thank you